# Certain .js pages not loading in time

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have certain pages on my site that loads a good amount of JavaScript files.  In the code below, `edit_onload(`) is in script1.js.  Typically all the scripts load fine and `edit_onload` fires successfully.  On occasion it *seems* like script1.js isn't loading in time because `edit_onload()` errors with object expected.  If you refresh the page everything will load fine.

My question is, shouldn't the `<script>` tag below wait for all of the .js files to load and then execute `edit_onload()`?

```
<script LANGUAGE="javascript" DEFER="true" for="window" event="onload">
            <xsl:comment>
                <![CDATA[
    
                edit_onload();
    
            ]]>
            </xsl:comment>
        </script>
        <script language="javascript" src="/_scripts/script1.js" defer="true"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="/_scripts/script2.js" defer="true"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="/_scripts/script3.js" defer="true"></script>
```

Comment: You should use `type="text/javascript"` instead of `language="javascript"`

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. It is just a reference, its not actually doing anything with that code till an event kicks off. And even if it did, the page would be on hold waiting for it to load. I'm guessing malformed data.

Comment: Could you be more specific on the malformed data idea Limey?

Comment: That your passing something into your JS code that is causing the issue, like maybe something that causes a loop to run extra long.  Its hard to tell without seeing the code.  How big is your JS file?  can you post your edit_onload?

Answer (score 0):

I think, an implementation of processing of deferred scripts is browser specific. For example, they can handle inline and external scripts in different queues. In general the 'defer' attribute is just a recommendation provided by a site developer for a user agent, but the user agent will not necessarily abide by the recommendation.

Also you should try using 'defer="defer"'. Can you move the call to the script1.js itself? Also you can periodically check an existence of a specific element moved to the end of the content being loaded and run the method only after the element is discovered.

BTW, you could possibly gain more control over script loading if you use a [dynamic script loading](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) metaphor (the link is just one of examples).